# write sql result multiple lines in a single line

Tags: sql, excel

I have a sql result which returns a column called description but the text in the description is stored in multiple lines. I want those lines to be stored as a single line in the row cell. I'm importing all this into an excel sheet which is creating a problem as the result is overflowing into other rows.

```
 Name=&quot;Table 3D effects 3&quot;/&gt;
&lt;w:LsdException Locked=&quot;false&quot; SemiHidden=&quot;true&quot;        
 Name=&quot;Table Contemporary&quot;/&gt;
&lt;w:LsdException Locked=&quot;false&quot; SemiHidden=&quot;true&quot;
```

I want this whole cell text in one line

Comment: why you put excel here? can you show us the query, and the result?  What is your db? please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: `cell.value = replace(value_from_db, vbcrlf, " ")`

Comment: Can't you just turn off the "Wrap text" option for said cell?

Comment: I just posted an example